# How to put value on input using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want to do is the setInterval function will continue produce value to `#test1` and if the user click the button the value of #test1 will be empty and back to 1 again sec after the button was clicked.

current output:  http://jsfiddle.net/eKWyY/43/

```
var tint = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        regain();   
    }, 500);    
$('#clickme').click(fuction(){
$('#test1').val('');                    
});
function regain(){
$('#test1').val("1");
}
```

Comment: There's a typo: "fuction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo...

Change:

```
$('#clickme').click(fuction(){
$('#test1').val('');                    
});
```

To:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $('#test1').val('');
});
```

You are missing the first `n` in `function`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGGHS/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is stop the interval after the user has clicked the button.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $('#test1').val('');   
    clearInterval(tint);                 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GF8B7/4/